# Remove loop device from container created by mknod

Tags: docker, containers

I have create loop device inside docker container using command,

`mknod -m660 /dev/loop10 b 7 10`

and then i have removed it using command,

`rm -rf /dev/loop10`

after this command, loop device successfully removed from container, i have checked it using

`ls -l /dev/loop*` command.

But when checked on host, that device is still present on it,
can anyone help me to delete loopdevice from container? and which also deletes it from host machie too.

I am inside docker container by using command,

`docker run -it --privileged --pid=host datamover:test bin/bash`

Comment: You'll have to circumvent a huge number of Docker settings to make this work.  It'll be easier and no more or less safe to run the process using `sudo` on the host.  "I need to create and delete synthetic host devices" suggests you don't want the isolation layer Docker provides.

Comment: Also note that the presence of a file in `/dev` doesn't necessarily mean the corresponding device actually exists; you can `mknod` with any major and minor numbers you want.

Comment: Devices in `/dev` (on your host) are managed automatically. The `/dev/loop[0-9]` devices exist not because you did something inside a container, but because the `loop` kernel module is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was i am able to create `mknod` from container which are also reflected in my host machine but when i delete that node, its removed from container but not from host machine.
After doing a lot of google search i have found the solution to the problem.
I just need to mount `/dev` directory inside docker container and i am now able to create & delete mknod from container which also reflected on host.

`docker run -it --privileged -v /dev:/dev datamover:test bin/bash`